# Socket.io identify each user

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, socket.io

I am making a chat application and I want people to be able to use specific usernames. I saw https://npmjs.com/socket.io.users, however, the last publication was 8 years ago. I also don't know how to really use socket.id to check for a username, since there is no identifiable information for the username, and the id changes for each socket/refresh.

How do I get the username of the person sending the message from the server side? I do not want to send it with the client side because I think that would be quite easy to bypass and send a message as any user, though it doesn't have to be insanely secure.

Sorry if this has been said before, everywhere I have checked talks about socket.id, but I don't think that can check what user is sending a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the chat application, you need to check each user if it is authenticated to send any message. so you could write a middleware on the server and attach the new property to the `socket`. Depending on your authentication mechanism you write a different logic but i will demonstrate on authentication by jwt.

```
const socketMiddleware = (socket, next) => {
  const token = socket.handshake.auth?.token;
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, YOUR_TOKEN_KEY);
    // decoded is the full jwt object. you could even destructure 
    socket.user = decoded;
  } catch (err) {
    const socketError = new Error("NOT_AUTHORIZED");
    return next(socketError);
  }
  next();
};
```

you need to register this middleware to the `io` not to the `express`

```
const socketMiddleware = require("./middleware/authSocketMiddleware");

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });

io.use((socket, next) => {
    socketMiddleware(socket, next);
  });
```

Now on the server, if user is authenticated, you have `socket.user` object. depending on how you constructed the `user` object in `jwt`, you could use `socket.user.user_id` or `socket.user.username`

Comment: Will try soon, currently messing around with CSS and other functionalities of the site. Looks like what I want though, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using one of the tutorials from https://socket.io (https://socket.io/get-started/chat) instead of an 8-year-old tutorial. This tutorial includes a username input dialog and features messages being sent with their username as the prefix.

Comment: This says at the bottom that you need to add the username functionality to it at the bottom (the link you sent).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).